# Django - inspectdb - the "models.FileField" are displayed as "models.CharField"

Tags: python, django, inspectdb

For some reason i want to check the Db as created with Django . I run command = `python manage.py inspectdb > inspectdb.txt`
I get to see = `models.CharField` in place of the expected = `models.FileField` , whereas the models.py has the correct `models.FileField` also the Db surely has a `models.FileField` as am able to store Files = .csv , in this case correctly.

My Question - Why would inspectdb , show the model field differently , how to learn more about this ?

Linked Question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48739612/4928635

Comment: How would Django make a difference between a `CharField` and a `FileField`? A `FileField` is at the database side just a charfield that stores the *path* of the file.

Comment: Aha!! - thanks . Am upvoting your answer . So i cant just use a inpectdb generated models.py to get to know if there are FileFields in there - cool makes sense, thanks.

Comment: yes, indeed that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That makes perfect sense, since a `FileField` is, at the database side, a `varchar`. The database does *not* store the *content* of the file. It stores at the database the path to where the file is stored on the disk (or another storage engine).

At the database side, there is thus no difference at all, it is only the Django *logic* that handles it differently. If you later analyze the database and aim to generate Django models out of it, then it will of course not by any means see a difference.

The `inspectdb` tool therefore is not the (perfect) inverse of the migration files that construct the database. `inspectdb` just makes models that indeed typecheck with the types at the database side. But a Django model is thus more "rich" in terms of logic than the database table counterpart.  Usually after running `inspectdb` it will require some "scaffolding" to ensure that the fields do proper validation, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> `FileField` instances are created in your database as `varchar` columns with a default max length of 100 characters. As with other fields, you can change the maximum length using the max_length argument.
>
> Note that whenever you deal with uploaded files, you should pay close attention to where you’re uploading them and what type of files they are, to avoid security holes. `Validate` all uploaded files so that you’re sure the files are what you think they are

Please check the docs of Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#filefield